# OCR - Text recognition from Image

Tags: machine-learning, optical-character-recognition

I plan to develop OCR application using tensorflow to get the value from the image. Text in the image may handwritting or text printed.

[image]

From the image, my ocr appplication will able to get the value of below:
1. ChequeDate
2. Payee Name
3. Legal Amount
4. Courtesy Amount

How the OCR application can get the value i want as highlighted as red color? is it need to crop it as small size of the picture for the OCR?

Comment: Hi. Please ask one question per post or seperate it to several different posts. Please edit the question or it may have to be closed. Thanks very much.

Comment: Edited. thanks ;)